# python while loop inside a for loop not breaking

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, break

Why wont this for loop break? all i get is the first letter of the stats variable and a count from 0 to infinite.

```
x = 0

for letter in range(0,len(stats)):
    while True:
        if stats[letter] != ',':
            x += 1
            print(stats[letter])
            print (x)
        elif stats[letter] == ',':
            break
    break
    print(stats[letter])
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to solve? Sadly, your actual code has a lot of logical mistakes :(

Comment: remove `while True:` and its `break`

Comment: The code falls into an infinite loop because `letter` never changed inside while loop.

Comment: From the looks of the code, It's hard to tell what you're actually trying to accomplish here -- however, I'm willing to bet that python has a cleaner way if you would let us know the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't break because your `letter` never gets changed in the while loop.  if

```
stats[letter] != ','
```

at the beginning of the `while` loop, then that branch will be taken over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

```
for letter in range(0,len(stats)-1):

    if stats[letter] != ',':
        x += 1
        print(stats[letter])
        print (x)
    elif stats[letter] == ',':
        break

print(stats[letter])
```

I think the above code is what you are after. You don't need the `while` loop, the `for` loop will test every letter in the string `stats` and will break when you get to a comma.

The last line will print either a comma, or the last letter if there's no comma in the string. Also I changed the loop limits as I think you'd get an error testing a character that doesn't exist.

EDIT: It works for me, although I think the other answer is a better way of doing this. I ran this test script below and it broke everytime it hit a comma.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def SO_answer(stats):

x = 0

for letter in range(0,len(stats)-1):
        if stats[letter] != ',':
            x += 1
            print(stats[letter])
            print (x)
        elif stats[letter] == ',':
            break

print(stats[letter])


SO_answer("test")

SO_answer("testing, 1, 2, 3")

SO_answer("Here's a long string with a comma at the end,")

SO_answer(",,,,,")
```

Comment: that sort of worked, however I got: t e s t , t as the output when test was the value of stats

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to solve? The builtin [enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) gives you an `index` and the `value` of an `iterable`.

```
>>> stats = 'this is my stats string, which is iterated until comma'
>>> for index, letter in enumerate(stats):
...     if letter == ',':
...         break
...     print index, letter
...     
... 
0 t
1 h
2 i
3 s
4  
5 i
6 s
7  
8 m
9 y
10  
11 s
12 t
13 a
14 t
15 s
16  
17 s
18 t
19 r
20 i
21 n
22 g
>>>
```